# Haskell game loop with keyboard handler

Tags: haskell, event-handling

This is function, that works correctly, but it seems to be too ugly.
`panel` argument is never used for anything but pushing into `refreshGamePanel`,
and it seems to be too much case statements. How can I cleanup this?

```
runGameLoop :: Game -> Panel -> Curses GameResult
runGameLoop game panel
  = if victory game then return Victory else
      refreshGamePanel game panel >> render >> getPanelWindow panel >>=
        flip getEvent (Just 1)
        >>=
        \ event' ->
          case event' of
              Nothing -> runGameLoop game panel
              Just event -> case event of
                EventSpecialKey (KeyFunction 2) -> return Restart
                EventSpecialKey (KeyFunction 10) -> return Quit
                EventSpecialKey key' -> case keyToDirection key' of
                  Nothing -> runGameLoop game panel
                  Just dir -> runGameLoop (makeMove game dir) panel
                _ -> runGameLoop game panel
```

Comment: Did you try to use `do` notation? Further, look for more idiomatic ways to deal with `Maybe` (how about `fromMaybe` ?).

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice language extension in GHC called [ViewPatterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns). Together with [LambdaCase](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/wp70x/lambdacase_and_multiway_if_added_to_ghc_head_for/) that fature allows you to shorten your code, I think. And `do` notation will be much more readable for imperative part.

```
runGameLoop game panel | victory game = return Victory
                       | otherwise = continue
    where
      anyEvent = gatPanelWindow panel >>= flip getEvent (Just 1)
      isRestart = (EventSpecialKey (KeyFunction 2) ==)
      isQuit = (EventSpecialKey (KeyFunction 10) ==)
      continue = do
          refreshGamePanel game panel
          render
          anyEvent >>= \case
              Just (isRestart -> True) -> return Restart
              Just (isQuit -> True) -> return Quit
              Just (EventSpecialKey (keyToDirection -> Just dir)) ->
                  runGameLoop (makeMove game dir) panel
              _ -> runGameLoop game panel
```

Another variant is to consider using of `Monad Maybe` instance

```
runGameLoop game panel = nextStep where
    anyEvent = gatPanelWindow panel >>= flip getEvent (Just 1)
    nextStep = if victory game then return Victory else do
        refreshGamePanel game panel
        render
        liftM react anyEvent >>= \case
            Just continuation -> continuation
            Nothing -> runGameLoop game panel
    react event' = do
        event' >>= \case
            EventSpecialKey (KeyFunction 2) -> return (return Restart)
            EventSpecialKey (KeyFunction 10) -> return (return Quit)
            EventSpecialKey key -> do
                dir <- keyToDirection key
                return (runGameLoop (makeMove game dir) panel)
            _ -> Nothing
```